# RMagick / Imagemagick string conversion UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I'm uploading pictures in different sizes with Paperclip. This all works fine. 
Now I'm adding a text layer with RMagick (annotate) to each photo for legal copyright info. This works fine too.

The problem starts when I'm trying to add the copyright symbol © to this string. It will add this dirty Â in front of the ©

My string now looks like this:

> Â© TheRestOfTheString

My code:

```
 myString = "TheRestOfTheString"
 @string = "(c) " + myString
```

The (c) genrates automatically a © symbol in my Coda editor. The file is UTF-8 coded. Where am I missing out?

Important to know:
on my mac (10.7, Imagemagick + RMagick) the string gets generated correctly, when I deploy to the server I gets this Â symbol in front of it.

Thanks in advance!
Wouter

Comment: Here's a recent related post on ensuring you have UTF-8 everywhere (http://rentzsch.tumblr.com/post/9133498042/howto-use-utf-8-throughout-your-web-stack). I'd first check to make sure you really have UTF-8 encoding through your entire stack and then, once that is done, check if you are really sending UTF-8 to ImageMagick/RMagick.

Comment: I fixed the problem. The problem was that my installed fonts weren't linked correctly with ImageMagick. I had to rebuild my type.xml file  with the imagemagick_type_gen script from this site: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/